# ruby small http server (tcp server) sending images through socket

Tags: ruby, sockets, tcp

I have created a small HTTP server with `TCPServer.new` the reason I haven't used any server libraries is I only have to serve a HTML page a JS file and some images.

I'm wondering how to send images when I receive request for a file `/favicon.ico` or `/head.jpg`. Should I use `socket.send`? Or should I send using buffer?

```
File.open('../Aimages/head.jpg', 'rb') do |file|
    while chunk = file.read(SIZE)
    socket.write(chunk)
  end
end
```

are headers important while sending images?

Comment: Why make yourself implement the HTTP protocol? Any reason to not use Sinatra?

Comment: I have quoted I just need to send very few files and I dont want my app to be heavy, thnx

Comment: Sinatra + thin is pretty lightweight.

Comment: Yes, you need headers and you also need to correctly implement an http parser and everything else.

Comment: You *always* need headers. There's really no reason not to use [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/) here, or at least implement [Rack](http://rack.github.com/). You're reinventing the wheel here. And really, if these are all static files, why not just let Nginx or Apache serve them?

Comment: I'm not creating a web app and my applications doesnot have complex server features, it just need http server which send a html file at a certain port, I may be re-inventing the wheel but I dont want to use a server when I can write few lines of code to make it working

Comment: But it doesn't make any sense! It doesn't matter how "simple" your requirements are, you still have to implement the HTTP spec. You could also use [WEBrick's HTTP server](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/webrick/rdoc/WEBrick/HTTPServer.html), which is included with every Ruby installation. If you do it yourself it won't be just a "few lines of code".

Comment: If it's really just HTML and images, why not Apache directly?

Comment: The reason people recommend NOT reinventing wheels, is you open yourself to attacks in all sorts of nasty ways if you don't reinvent the fixes and protections too. Saying "I dont want my app to be heavy" can likely mean it won't take a heavy exploit to break you too. Just something to think about.